# angular 8 use last http request response

Tags: angular, http

I am using angular 8. On my list page I have some filters. On filter value change an http request is called. When user change filter too frequently multiple api request initiated. My first request take more time then last one, so on page I got old filter values. How I can get latest request response values?

I tried switchMap

```
this.dataService.getData(params)
      .pipe(switchMap(response => of(response)))
      .subscribe(response => {
        this.data = response;       
      });
```

Answer (score 1):

`switchMap` works by cancelling previous request when a new value is provided. In your code you create new observable each time, so there's nothing to cancel.

You would need to have a long-running observable over filter params. Then you can subscribe to the results of this observable using `switchMap` and get the data from the service.
Something like this:

Component:

```js
@Component({})
export class ExampleComponent implements OnDestroy {
  private readonly _paramsSubject: BehaviorSubject<any>(null); // Here are the filters

  readonly data$ = this._paramsSubject
    .pipe(switchMap(params => this.dataService.getData(params))); // subscribe to the filter changes and switchMap to data service 

  setFilters(filters: any) {
    // push new filters into the subject
    this._paramsSubject.next(filters);
  }

  ngOnDestroy() {
    // need to close the subject
    this._paramsSubject.complete();
  }
}
```

Template:

```html
<!-- Click on this button would update filters and trigger data loading -->
<button type="button" (click)="setFilters('new_filter')">Set filters</button>

<div *ngIf="data$ | async; let data">
    <!-- Data is available here -->
    {{data | json}}
</div>
```

Note: `BehaviorSubject` is used here to have an initial value of `null` when calling data service. If you don't need to call data service until user selects the filters first, then you can replace `BehaviourSubject` with a usual one

Also the `async` pipe is not strictly necessary, you can just subscribe to the params subject in your `ngOnInit()` method, but it's preferable to use the `async` pipe in such use cases.

---

As a bonus, now you can expand your pipe. Some useful operators for your case:

- `debounceTime` - discard fast changes to filters
  ([documentation](https://www.learnrxjs.io/operators/filtering/debounce.html));
- `distinctUntilChanged` - make requests only when filters were really
  changed ([documentation](https://www.learnrxjs.io/operators/filtering/distinctuntilchanged.html)).